# How to get last value when combining two value if first value is null?

Tags: sql, database

I have a sql query which combines firstname and lastname. But if there is no firstname an there is value in second name then then result of combination is null

```
select  CompanyContact.FirstName + ' '
 + COALESCE(CompanyContact.LastName, '')  AS Name
from bsDocument 
LEFT JOIN Contact AS CompanyContact ON CompanyContact.ContactID = bsDocument.DocumentContactID

 WHERE   bsDocument.SellerID = 3632
AND bsDocument.Module = 'bsContract'
```

In the following column the value of CompanyContact.FirstName  is null and the value of CompanyContact.LastName is 'Dahal' but the result is displayed as null. How can i fix this?

Comment: Do you still want the space in front of the last name?

Comment: NULL + String = NULL in SQL. So if there probability of having NULL in either part, please handle ISNULL() in both first name and last name part. Hope the output will be as your expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `concat()`

```
select concat(CompanyContact.FirstName,' ',CompanyContact.LastName)  AS Name
from bsDocument 
LEFT JOIN Contact AS CompanyContact ON CompanyContact.ContactID = bsDocument.DocumentContactID
WHERE   bsDocument.SellerID = 3632
AND bsDocument.Module = 'bsContract'
```

Answer (score 1):

use `COALESCE` in FirstName as like lastname

```
select COALESCE(CompanyContact.FirstName,'') + ' '
 + COALESCE(CompanyContact.LastName, '')  AS Name
from bsDocument 
LEFT JOIN Contact AS CompanyContact ON CompanyContact.ContactID = bsDocument.DocumentContactID

 WHERE   bsDocument.SellerID = 3632
AND bsDocument.Module = 'bsContract'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stuff()` with string concatenation:

```
select stuff((coalesce(' ' + c.FirstName, '') +
              coalesce(' ' + c.LastName, ''),
             ), 1, 1, '') as Name
from bsDocument d left join
     Contact c
     on c.ContactID = d.DocumentContactID
where d.SellerID = 3632 and
      d.Module = 'bsContract';
```

This has the nice property of only including spaces *between* the first and last name.  This structure readily extends to as many null-able strings as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use a CASE expression:

```
SELECT
CASE 
    WHEN NULLIF(CompanyContact.FirstName, '') IS NULL THEN CompanyContact.LastName
    ELSE CompanyContact.FirstName + ' ' + CompanyContact.LastName
    END AS Name
FROM bsDocument 
LEFT JOIN Contact AS CompanyContact ON CompanyContact.ContactID = bsDocument.DocumentContactID
WHERE bsDocument.SellerID = 3632
AND bsDocument.Module = 'bsContract'
```